# Django class based view, save in another model after CreateView

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I have a create view (Loan_assetCreateView(generic.CreateView)) where I save if an asset is going to be loaned and when it will be returened in a model called Loan_asset(models.Model). Then I have the asset in a diffrent model Asset(model.Model). I would like to once I have saved my data in my Loan_assetCreateView(generic.CreateView) that is set the value in Asset.is_loaned to True. How can I do that?

My models.py:

```
class Asset(models.Model):

    # Relationships
    room = models.ForeignKey("asset_app.Room", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    model_hardware = models.ForeignKey("asset_app.Model_hardware", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)

    # Fields
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    serial = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    mac_address = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    purchased_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    may_be_loaned = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
    is_loaned = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
    missing = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
    notes = HTMLField(default="")
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=90, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)

class Loan_asset(models.Model):

    # Relationships
    asset = models.ForeignKey("asset_app.Asset", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    loaner_type = models.ForeignKey("asset_app.Loaner_type", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey("asset_app.Locations", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)

    # Fields
    loaner_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    loaner_address = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    loaner_telephone_number = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    loaner_email = models.EmailField()
    loaner_quicklink = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    loan_date = models.DateField()
    return_date = models.DateField()
    notes = HTMLField(default="")
    returned = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    class Meta:
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.loaner_name)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("asset_app_loan_asset_detail", args=(self.pk,))

    def get_update_url(self):
        return reverse("asset_app_loan_asset_update", args=(self.pk,))
```

my urls.py

```
`path("asset_app/loan_asset/create/", views.Loan_assetCreateView.as_view(), name="asset_app_loan_asset_create")`,
```

my views.py

```
class Loan_assetCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    model = models.Loan_asset
    form_class = forms.Loan_assetForm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some options:

- override [form_valid](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2a04e24d2dfc8e60a66e4369d970913cb2112d91/django/views/generic/edit.py#L70) method that's being called in `post` method implementation, so that after form will be validated (model instance saved), you'll be able to set the flag through foreign key/by creating Asset instance:

```py
...

def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save()

    if self.object.asset:
        self.object.asset.is_loaned = True
    else:
        self.object.asset = Asset.objects.create(is_loaned=True) 
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

- use [Django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/signals/):

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=Loan_asset)
def create_transaction(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Asset.objects.create(is_loaned=True)
```

Comment: Loved the Django signal solution

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `post` method in your `Loan_assetCreateView`.

```
class Loan_assetCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    model = models.Loan_asset
    form_class = forms.Loan_assetForm
    
    def post(request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().post(request, *args. **kwargs)
        # Do your thing
        return response
```